# Group sale by days using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, aggregate-functions

I need to group sales by days or weeks, but I get the graph like this

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfbk7.png)

this is the view code
function datagrafico(base_url){

```
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: base_url + "index.php/Admin/getDataDias",
                                        type:"POST",
                                        dataType:"json",
                                        success:function(data){
                                            var dias = new Array();
                                            var montos = new Array();
                                            $.each(data,function(key, value){
                                                dias.push(value.fecha_actualizacion);
                                                valor = Number(value.monto);
                                                montos.push(valor);
                                            });
                                            graficar(dias,montos);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
```

plotOptions: {
column: {
pointPadding: 0.2,
borderWidth: 0
},
series:{
dataLabels:{
enabled:true,
formatter:function(){
return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y)
}

```
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    series: [{
                                        name: 'Dias',
                                        data: montos

                                    }]
```

this is the controller

```
public function getDataDias(){
    
    $resultados = $this->model_venta->montos();
    echo json_encode($resultados);
}
```

and this is the models

```
public function montos(){
    $this->db->select("fecha_actualizacion, SUM(total) as monto");
    $this->db->from("venta");
    $this->db->where("pago_id","2");
    $this->db->where("estado","1");
    $this->db->group_by('fecha_actualizacion');
    $this->db->order_by('fecha_actualizacion');
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    return $resultados->result();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We strongly prefer that you include your code and examples in your question as *text*, not as images. Please [edit] your question. You can indent code and data 4 spaces, and it shows up without other formatting.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code or error messages and do not link to external sources. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be 

searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image, links can get obsolete. Code should be included as text in the question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your php query code like this.

```php
$this->db->select('DATE(fecha) AS fecha, SUM(total) AS monto');
...
$this->db->group_by('DATE(fecha)');
$this->db->order_by('DATE(fecha)');
...
```

In this case you use `DATE(fecha)` to truncate the DATETIME (or TIMESTAMP) values in your `fecha` column to calendar days.